# Using an if statement involving time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've been trying to get an if statement to run if it is a certain time, and been trying this:

```
import datetime
try:
    while True:
        if(datetime.datetime.now().time() == (6, 20, 0, 0)):
            print("It's 6:20!")
except :
    pass
```

But nothing happens at 6:20.. why and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are calling doesn't return a tuple; it returns a `datetime.time` instance. Also, the odds of you calling the function at *exactly* 6:20 are vanishingly small.

```
success = False
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    if now.hour == 6 and now.minute == 20:
        success = True
        print("It's 6:20!")
```

More than likely, you simply want to break out of the loop once `success` becomes true, meaning your code would look more like

```
while True:
    now = ...
    if now.hour == 6 ...:
        print("It's 6:20!")
        break
```

Comment: If I were to add "and 1>=now.second>=0" would that work?

Comment: `and t.second == 0` would suffice. A separate field, `t.microsecod`, stores the fractional second as an integer number of microseconds.

Comment: So to deal with the small chance to run exactly at 6:20 what should I do? I want it to just run the code under the if once, but when I've been testing it will either completely skip it or spam me with "It's 6:20!"

Comment: You need to add an explicit flag that gets set the first time `now` returns a value that occurs during `6:20:00`.